# How to get Lexmark X2600 printer to work?

Tags: printing, lexmark

If anyone can explain please can it be step by step? I just got on here using Ubuntu 12.04 and I just went and got a Lexmark X2600 printer. I just wish it was as simple as Windows, but no.

This is the only printer that seems to not be in the search thing and I looked on here and these guys just seem to be talking in another world to me. Please break it down to me, and what do I need to get or do?

Answer (score 3):

**For Ubuntu 32 bits**

1. Download this [file](http://www.downloaddelivery.com/downloads/cpd/lexmark-inkjet-08-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh.zip) to a directory.
2. Unpackage the zip (unzip ***.zip )
3. Execute the script (sudo sh ***.rpm.sh)
4. Fill in your device ( x2600) and name it (whatever order it should be)

**For Ubuntu 64 bits**

For this you'll need to install the 32-bit CUPS libraries, to match the 32-bit install script.

1. On a terminal execute:

> sudo apt-get install libcups

1. Download the file from Lexmark (***.rpm.sh.zip )
2. Unpackage the zip (unzip ***.zip )
3. Execute the script (sudo sh ***.rpm.sh)
4. Fill in your device ( x2600) and name it (whatever order it should be)
5. Start the maintenance option when the install was finished and test the printer

Comment: This answer is for 32 bit or 64 bit too?

Comment: The solution presented above was for 32 bits, i will also add the 64 bits.

Comment: ok. but on ubuntu 12.04 the packages is name libcups2 and is already installed...

Comment: But you also need the driver, for the printer, presented on point 1